# object - array of object - save in variable in Javascript - React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

How to map, or iterate over this Json and save attribute's values in an array, to insert in a

const variable = data.attributes.map(values => )

I need to do something like that in react, any ideas

something like that

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "video",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Lo nuevo",
        "description": "este es el nuevo video",
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehjKFJsMVy0",
        "year": "2020-01-22",
        "author": "Muriño"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "type": "video",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "moriria besandote",
        "description": "video musical willie garcia",
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KF_w43OqeVA",
        "year": "2012-01-22",
        "author": "Willie Garcia"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "type": "video",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Moriria Besandote",
        "description": "Mira el video oficial del éxito de la salsa romántica “Moriria Besandote“",
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KF_w43OqeVA",
        "year": "2012-01-22",
        "author": "Willie Garcia"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "type": "video",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Corazon de acero",
        "description": "El Nuevo Album De Yiyo Sarante La Voz De La Salsa ",
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUV55lGPGaY",
        "year": "2016-01-22",
        "author": "Yiyo Sarante"
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: How the array should look like with the sample JSON data you provided?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do you have any code? Show us what you have done so far. If you are looking for tutorials, this is not the correct site. If you have a specific question, you need to show your code, expected result and actual result.

Comment: This is easy to do, but we need some help. Data transformation questions should always include the input and expected output of the transformation process. Please edit your question to include both.

Comment: can you show us the output result of the operation you want to carry out ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are asking. This code loops through the data array and retrieves just the attribute objects. Using `.map()` then places them each into an element of the array that is returned.

So you have an array of attribute objects or, as you stated "*attribute's values in an array*".

```js
var json = `{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "video",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Lo nuevo",
        "description": "este es el nuevo video",
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehjKFJsMVy0",
        "year": "2020-01-22",
        "author": "Muriño"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "type": "video",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "moriria besandote",
        "description": "video musical willie garcia",
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KF_w43OqeVA",
        "year": "2012-01-22",
        "author": "Willie Garcia"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "type": "video",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Moriria Besandote",
        "description": "Mira el video oficial del éxito de la salsa romántica “Moriria Besandote“",
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KF_w43OqeVA",
        "year": "2012-01-22",
        "author": "Willie Garcia"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "type": "video",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Corazon de acero",
        "description": "El Nuevo Album De Yiyo Sarante La Voz De La Salsa ",
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUV55lGPGaY",
        "year": "2016-01-22",
        "author": "Yiyo Sarante"
      }
    }
  ]
}`;

const data = JSON.parse(json).data;

const out = data.map(d=>d.attributes);

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let response = {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "video",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Lo nuevo",
        "description": "este es el nuevo video",
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehjKFJsMVy0",
        "year": "2020-01-22",
        "author": "Muriño"
      }
    },
......
}

response.data.map((item, i) => {
  Object.values(item.attributes).map( val => {
    // now you have access to the attributes's values
    console.log(val);
   // you can save them in variable 
   // declare a varibale 'arr' and push the required value to it
   arr.push(val.title) // for example
  })
})
```

if you need to have access to both keys and values

```
response.data.map((item, i) => {
  Object.entries(item.attributes).map( ([key, val]) => {
    // now you have access to the attributes's values and keys
    console.log(val , key);
  })
})
```